# Let $S\neq\varnothing$ and $G$ be a group. Show the set $M(S,G)$ of mapping from $S$ to $G$ is a group and $fg(x)=f(x)g(x)$ for $f,g\in M(S,G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

> Let $S$ be a nonempty set and $G$ be a group. Show the set $M(S,G)$ of mapping from $S$ to $G$ is a group and $fg(x)=f(x)g(x)$ for $f,g \in M(S,G)$.

Here is my proof,

Let $x\in S$ and $f,g \in M(S,G),$ then $fg(x)=f(x)g(x)\in G \implies fg \in M(S,G)$

Now let $e\in G$ be the identity, and define $i(x)=e, \forall x \in S$, then $if(x)=i(x)f(x)=ef(x)=f(x) \because f(x) \in G$

hence, there exists an identity.

Now, define $I(x)=f(x)^{-1}$, then $If(x)=I(x)f(x)=f(x)^{-1}f(x)=i(x)$, hence every $f\in M(S,G)$ has an inverse.
M(S,G) is a group.

> Is this the correct way to prove some set is a group? I am not sure if I can define maps for identity and inverse.

Comment: I suspect you mean to say you want to prove $M(S, G)$ is a group where the group operation is defined to mean $f \cdot g: x \mapsto f(x)g(x)$.  You need to prove that the proposed group operation is associative.  That follows immediately from the fact that the group operation within $G$ is associative but you still need to say it.  The rest of your proof looks fine.

Comment: I would also add that your notation for the inverse of $f$ is poor; $I(x)$ does not make any reference to $f$. It would be better if you somehow indicated that its values depend on $f$, e.g., by calling it $I_f$ or something like that.

Comment: This is just the Cartesian product $G^S$.